# Vimeo videos not showing fullscreen option in production

Tags: angular, iframe, fullscreen, vimeo

I'm using the following code to play youtube/vimeo videos
Everything seems to be working fine in local(localhost).
But when I go to my production website, vimeo video player is not giving me an option to play video in fullscreen

HTML: **<iframe id="video" width="800" title="course-video" class="embed-responsive-size" allow="autoplay" [src]="videoLink" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="allowFullScreen" style="padding-left: 0px;">**

Thanks in Advance!

How can I fix this so that vimeo gives an option to play video in full scree